# Help identifying another connector

Tags: identification, connector, power-connector

I'm trying to identify this 2-pin connector.  Would anyone happen to know what type it is / who makes it? I was in touch with a Molex support representative this morning and they told me it wasn't one of theirs.

[image: unknown connector]

Comment: I found similar connectors by using the search term "T-type automotive connector" but am unable to find an official spec.

Comment: they do look close, thanks for the lead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called FASTON. More precisely: Fastons are the metal pieces that are crimped on a wire, they are inside plastic cover to make a two-terminal connector. Search for "faston cover" or "faston connector". It is probably 6.3 mm faston, that is standard size. The plastic piece may be available in many slightly different sizes that look similar.

Comment: This looks like a very close match: 
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/1-180908-0/2279612

Will snag a few and give them a try. Thank you for your help!